# Firedac - Datasnap + FDMemtable + fkInternalCalc

Tags: delphi, firedac, fdmemtable

I have had some problems with these fields **fkInternalCalc** to migrate from TClientDataSet to TFDMemtable.

We use these fields to manipulate data in memory time, but these fields mustn't be persisted. I mean, these fields "fkInternalCalc" are very useful.

We have an aplication datasnap and we created one generic method to recovery from the server a "TFDJSONDataSets"

```
procedure TProxyExec.Open(const DataSet: TFDMemTable; Query: String;
const TipoSever: TipoServerDB);
var
   Dados: TFDJSONDataSets;
begin
   try
      GetDataSet(Query,Dados,TipoSever);
      DataSet.Close;
      DataSet.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(Dados,0));
   finally
      FreeAndNil(Dados);
   end;
end;
```

Everything is working when the dataset does not have fields fkInternalCalc, but when it comes a field configured as fkInternalCalc, houston we have a problem hahaha

When I execute the instruction below;

```
DataSet.AppendData(TFDJSONDataSetsReader.GetListValue(Dados,0));
```

It Occours the error the following error; [Imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su1Hy.png)

> Debugger Exception Notification  Programa.exe raised exception dass
>   EFDException with message IFireDAC] [DatS]-38. Cannot change table
>   [fdmTabela] structure, when table has rows'.

I debuged using .dcus option, but, I couldn't find the solution.
Could someone help me?

We are currently using XE7 - Update1

best regards!

Comment: Este é apenas o site em inglês. você poderia, por favor, traduzir sua pergunta para o inglês para os outros? Opcionalmente, você pode usar o [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/). Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ow! Sorry Victoria, I try translate for all.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you do not use JSON in the transport layer?